# Can't scrape some tables with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I was able to write a simple script to grab tables from etfdb.com However, some of the tables are not working. I think because they are dynamic and not static tables. I was wondering if someone could share some insight on how I could grab these.

Does not work:
https://etfdb.com/etfs/style/value/

Works fine:
https://etfdb.com/compare/market-cap/

My original code:

```
def get_etfs(url, table_num):
  webpage = requests.get(url)
  soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage.content, "html.parser")
  soup_table = soup.find("table")
  tables = pd.read_html(str(soup_table))
  df = tables[table_num]
  print(df)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jeremy!

I have tested your code here, by changing this line:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage.text, "lxml")
```

It worked! Usually, when I scrape some webpage, we access the text from the page. And also, I prefer to keep the standard parser - lxml.